# How to make the image in the second column of the table fill the whole column from top to bottom ignoring the padding applied to 1st column?

Tags: html, css, html-email, css-tables

I am trying to make an element for email newsletter with two columns using tables but I can not understand how to fix the following issue: How to make the image in the second column of the table fill the whole column from top to bottom ignoring the padding applied to 1st column?

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsZis.png)

[The failing result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4cPi.png)

```
<tr>
                                        <td style="background-color:#e9e9e9; padding:0;">
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:60%; padding:30px;">
                                                        <h3>Срок завершения работ - 01.09.2023</h3>
                                                        <p style="margin-top:8px; margin-bottom:8px;"><strong>Всего 25 апартаментов.</strong></p>
                                                        <p style="margin-top:8px; margin-bottom:8px;"><strong>Редкие планировки - от 25 м².</strong></p>
                                                        <p style="margin-top:8px; margin-bottom:8px;"><strong>Высота потолка - 3 м.</strong></p>
                                                        <p style="margin-top:8px; margin-bottom:8px;"><strong>Апартаменты с отделкой:</strong> стены выкрашены в светлые тона, плитка в с/у, на полу паркет, выполнена разводка электрики и сделаны основные выводы.</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width:40%;">
                                                        <img src="images/image-card-1.png" alt="Image Column" style="width:100%; height:100%; max-width:100%; max-height: 100%; object-fit:contain;">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>

</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: It's correct as-is. You may need to share more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting padding-top:0px and padding-bottom:0px for an image.

Comment: Have tried that, still no results, the solution was to set line-height:0px; of a parent <td>. Maybe it's a bit of dirty coding but it really saved me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).